# How to dynamically set ion-radio in Ionic?

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have simple list of users:

```
<ion-scroll scrollY="true">
    <ion-item *ngFor="let user of listOfUsers" [(ngModel)]="selectedUser">
        <ion-label>{{ user.title }}</ion-label>
        <ion-radio value="{{ user.value }}" (ionSelect)="OnUserChanged(user)"></ion-radio>
    </ion-item>
</ion-scroll>
```

What I want to do is to somehow to set that by default specific user would be selected. For example by default `listOfUsers[0]` would be selected.

I tried to add `[(ngModel)]="selectedUser"` in different places and attach to it `listOfUsers[0]` but each time getting different errors...

Answer (score 0):

I think you would be better of with a FormControlName.

Where you can create a FormControlGroup for a User, with a FormControl for the radio-button. Or if the user doesn't have any other properties just the FormControl.

You can then use formControl.SetValue() to set the value.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the checked property of a radio button:

```
<ion-scroll scrollY="true">
<ion-item *ngFor="let user of listOfUsers" [(ngModel)]="selectedUser">
    <ion-label>{{ user.title }}</ion-label>
    <ion-radio [checked]="checkDefault(user)" value="{{ user.value }}" (ionSelect)="OnUserChanged(user)"></ion-radio>
</ion-item>
```

In your TS file, you create the `checkDefault()` function (give it any name you want).
In this function, you can check whether the user is the default value, if it is return true, else return false.

```
  public checkDefault(user: User): boolean {
if(user.uniqueId === default.uniqueId) {
  return true;
} else return false;
```

};

If this does not do the trick, or if this is not the way you want to do it let me know.